# An error occurred while creating a bitcoin price notification Telegram chatbot (PytzUsageWarning)

Tags: telegram, chatbot

```
import requests
import telegram
import json
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
import time
import sys
import pandas as pd
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.base import JobLookupError

dt = requests.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD,EUR')
print(dt.text)
price_now = dt.json()

bot_token = "5668522544:AAFqNFcgd5wDBtQbJBhRayfPx9VpVPVjcyQ"
Cointimeline = telegram.Bot(token=bot_token)
updates = Cointimeline.getUpdates()

for i in updates:
    print(i.message)


class Chatbot:
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.core = telegram.Bot(token)
        self.updater = Updater(token)
        self.id = 5734902861

    def sendmsg(self, text):
        self.core.sendmsg(chat_id=self.id, text=text)

    def stop(self):
        self.updater.stop()


class Alert(Chatbot):
    def __init__(self):
        self.token = '5668522544:AAFqNFcgd5wDBtQbJBhRayfPx9VpVPVjcyQ'
        Chatbot.__init__(self, self.token)
        self.updater.stop()

    def controller(self, cmd, func):
        self.updater.dispatcher.controller(CommandHandler(smd, func))

    def start(self):
        self.sendMessage('')


aps = BlockingScheduler()


def push():
    dt = requests.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD,EUR")
    ALERTBOT = Alert()
    ALERTBOT.sendmsg(dt.text)a

    price_now = pd.DataFrame({"USD": {list(dt.json().values())[0]}, "EUR": [list(dt.json().values())[1]]})

    data = pd.read_csv("ALERTBOT.csv")
    data = data.append(price_now, sort=True)
    data = data.loc[:, 'USD':'EUR']
    data.to_csv("ALERTBOT.csv")

aps.add_job(push, 'interval', seconds=60)
aps.start()
```

The error continues to occur.

> PytzUsageWarning: The zone attribute is specific to pytz's interface; please migrate to a new time zone provider. For more details on how to do so, see https://pytz-deprecation-shim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html
> if obj.zone == 'local':

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the pytz library being out of date. You can solve the problem by updating the library:

```
pip install --upgrade pytz
```